# Switching the order of multiple sets of elements with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, switch-statement, swap

I have a number of elements on a page which contain a header and an image, which I would like to change the order of.  E.g switching the order of the img with the h2:

```
<section>
  <img>
  <h2></h2>
</section>
```

I have multiple instances of the section, so have tried to iterate each in turn as:

```
$("section h2").each(function(){
    $(this).before($(this).prev('img'));    
});
```

but this isn't having any effect.  Can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: can you post a fiddle?  most likely, you are not `remove()`ing the old ones once you've added new ones

Comment: from docs `Insert content, specified by the parameter, before each element in the set of matched elements.` so you are inserting img before this - which is why it doesn't change

Comment: Thanks @JoeCoderGuy but VisioN's answer below solved it.  My fiddle's at http://jsfiddle.net/DhCDp/ for anyone interested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`insertBefore()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/) will work perfectly:

```
$("section h2").each(function() {
    $(this).insertBefore($(this).prev("img"));
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/kqLeD/

Comment: Perfect, thanks.  My confusion between .before() and .insertBefore()